# How can I work on .txt file and distinguish between a new line and paragraph

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of .txt files which content I want to convert to html with paragraphs and headings.
Now, the issue is that the content of these files is copy/pasted from elsewhere and formatting was lost in the process. Every line is counted as a separate line while the content itself, visually, looks formatted with separated paragraphs.

This is how one of the .txt files look

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Vestibulum varius ultricies libero a sollicitudin.

Curabitur non ornare nisl, at bibendum neque. Nam ultrices lacus vel eleifend aliquam. 
Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed molestie nulla sed ex mollis 
fringilla. Donec dignissim odio sit amet posuere porttitor. Suspendisse nibh erat, 
convallis eu pretium sit amet, pretium sit amet ante. Nullam semper vitae sapien vitae ullamcorper. Maecenas a 
tincidunt metus, vel accumsan massa. Morbi 
at enim ullamcorper, consectetur tortor placerat, ultrices est. Nullam 
imperdiet leo non erat faucibus, nec sagittis nulla egestas. Morbi ac lectus nunc. 
Maecenas suscipit, neque vel placerat egestas, quam ante efficitur augue, ac sodales quam diam et nisl. Phasellus maximus lacus sed nunc malesuada tincidunt.

Cras fermentum, dolor a sollicitudin fermentum, turpis 
lectus commodo augue, ac blandit magna justo quis nisl. 
Pellentesque sed nisi ultricies, pulvinar tellus sit 
amet, facilisis augue.
```

Here it looks like it's separated in paragraphs, but when i do readlines() it reads each line separately, so my question is: How can I convert these lines into paragraphs.

This is how it's supposed to be when i manually edit it. [Here you can see numbered paragraphs where the whole paragraph is 105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loREo.png), and [Here's unedited version where you can see each line is numbered as a separate line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRW29.png)

So my desired result is

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<h1>

<h2>Vestibulum varius ultricies libero a sollicitudin.<h2>

<p>Curabitur non ornare nisl, at bibendum neque. Nam ultrices lacus vel eleifend aliquam. 
Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed molestie nulla sed ex mollis 
fringilla. Donec dignissim odio sit amet posuere porttitor. Suspendisse nibh erat, 
convallis eu pretium sit amet, pretium sit amet ante. Nullam semper vitae sapien vitae ullamcorper. Maecenas a 
tincidunt metus, vel accumsan massa. Morbi 
at enim ullamcorper, consectetur tortor placerat, ultrices est. Nullam 
imperdiet leo non erat faucibus, nec sagittis nulla egestas. Morbi ac lectus nunc. 
Maecenas suscipit, neque vel placerat egestas, quam ante efficitur augue, ac sodales quam diam et nisl. Phasellus maximus lacus sed nunc malesuada tincidunt.</p>

<p>Cras fermentum, dolor a sollicitudin fermentum, turpis 
lectus commodo augue, ac blandit magna justo quis nisl. 
Pellentesque sed nisi ultricies, pulvinar tellus sit 
amet, facilisis augue.</p>
```

H tags are hardcoded, they share titles throughout the files but paragraphs differ.
I tried with `.replace('\n', '')` but then it just becomes a huge string. I need this whole paragraph to be read as a line with `readlines()` function so i can put `<p>` tag around it

Comment: I'd replace all newline that is followed by an empty line with a special symbol, remove all newlines that are left, and restore that special symbol back into newline.

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `\n\n'' which appears to separate the paragraphs? Although, how you differentiate between a paragraph and a heading is another issue.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony these headings are hardcoded into constant because they are same for each file, so I first compare line to the constants. Tried with ``\n\n`` but the end result is still the same, even if i rewrite the file.  
@Martheen gonna try your method aswell, sounds interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the files have exactly two headers and at least one paragraph, you can try :

```
from pathlib import Path

dirfiles = "tmp" # put the actual dir

for fp in Path(dirfiles).glob("*.txt"):
    with (
        open(fp, "r") as inf,
        open(Path(dirfiles) / f"{fp.stem}.html", "w") as ouf
    ):

        h1, h2, *pgs = inf.read().split("\n\n")

        tags = (
            f"<h1>{h1}</h1>",
            f"<h2>{h2}</h2>",
            "\n\n".join(f"<p>{p.strip()}</p>" for p in pgs)
        )

        ouf.write("\n\n".join(tags))
```

Output of `"\n\n".join(tags)` :

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>

<h2>Vestibulum varius ultricies libero a sollicitudin.</h2>

<p>Curabitur non ornare nisl, at bibendum neque. Nam ultrices lacus vel eleifend aliquam. 
Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed molestie nulla sed ex mollis 
fringilla. Donec dignissim odio sit amet posuere porttitor. Suspendisse nibh erat, 
convallis eu pretium sit amet, pretium sit amet ante. Nullam semper vitae sapien vitae ullamcorper. Maecenas a 
tincidunt metus, vel accumsan massa. Morbi 
at enim ullamcorper, consectetur tortor placerat, ultrices est. Nullam 
imperdiet leo non erat faucibus, nec sagittis nulla egestas. Morbi ac lectus nunc. 
Maecenas suscipit, neque vel placerat egestas, quam ante efficitur augue, ac sodales quam diam et nisl. Phasellus maximus lacus sed nunc malesuada tincidunt.</p>

<p>Cras fermentum, dolor a sollicitudin fermentum, turpis 
lectus commodo augue, ac blandit magna justo quis nisl. 
Pellentesque sed nisi ultricies, pulvinar tellus sit 
amet, facilisis augue.</p>
```

Comment: Ohh man, you just saved me! This is probably a perfect solution for the issue. `.split("\n\n")` works basically just like `.readlines()` and even better because it works on both formatted, and not properly formatted .txt files!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding ;) Btw, I made a small fix. `h2` instead of `h1`.